# Help with derivation (just a single step)

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to understand the following step in a derivation:

[Step where I need help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mWZV.png)

Could anyone explain the process?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that step (12) $\epsilon\nabla^2 L(z,\hat{\theta})$ can be dropped. Then the equation becomes $\nabla_{\epsilon} \approx -[\nabla^2 R(\hat{\theta})]^{-1} \cdot [\nabla R(\hat{\theta}) + \epsilon \nabla^2 L(z,\hat{\theta})]$. '$\hat{\theta}$ minimizes R' means that the gradient of R, $\nabla R(\hat{\theta})$, shoule be $0$. As a result $\nabla_{\epsilon} \approx -[\nabla^2 R(\hat{\theta})]^{-1} \cdot [\epsilon \nabla^2 L(z,\hat{\theta})]$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the power series $(1-x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots$, we have

$$(a-b\epsilon)^{-1} = \frac {1/a}{1-b\epsilon/a} = \frac1a\left(1 + \frac {b\epsilon}a + \left(\frac {b\epsilon}a\right)^2 + \dots\right) = a^{-1}(1+o(\epsilon))$$

Therefore

\begin{align}
\Delta_\epsilon &\approx -[\nabla^2R(\hat \theta) + \epsilon\nabla^2L(2,\hat\theta)]^{-1}[\nabla R(\hat\theta) + \epsilon\nabla L(z,\hat\theta)]\\
&=-(\nabla^2R(\hat \theta))^{-1}(1 + o(\epsilon))[0+\epsilon\nabla L(z,\hat\theta)]\\
&\approx-\nabla^2R(\hat \theta)^{-1}\nabla L(z,\hat\theta)\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Should it be $(1+o(1)$ on the second line? You get $o(\epsilon)$ with the ε in the $L$ factor, and you can only then ignore it

Comment: The $o(\epsilon)$ term comes from the power series expansion. Also since $1$ is $o(1)$, writing $1+o(1)$ does not make sense.